# White dialog windows in dark theme, Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: themes, 19.04, appearance

After upgrading to 19.04 I've noticed that some dialog windows are still white even while using a dark theme  (Adwaita-dark in my case).

[image: Power Off window]

Is there any way to make these windows dark like the rest of the theme?

Comment: Ddi you enable global dark theme?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.